# How can I write exceptions in a text file using C# & webdriver?This is for creating logs whenever a script fails

Tags: webdriver

How can I write exceptions in a text file using C# & webdriver?

This is for creating logs whenever a script fails.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for [log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/). This is a very feasible solution for logging. This gives you the opportunity to create .txt files as well as lot others. You may need to understand the configuration little bit which is not too bad either. Here is the [details](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/features.html). This gives you the opportunity of multiple level logging Such as *fatal, error, info* etc.

Speaking about `logging` and `Selenium`:
There is a logging feature going to be introduced to `Selenium` soon. It's still in progress. See [this](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Logging#Logging_in_WebDriver)
There is also a native [class](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/logging/LoggingPreferences.html) exist for `java`. Unfortunately not for c# as per my knowledge.

A step by step description [here](http://www.eyecatch.no/blog/2012/08/logging-with-log4net-in-c-sharp/)